# How to call Biztalk orchestrations without using the messagebox

Tags: biztalk

Is there anyway you could call a Biztalk orchestration without placing a message in the messagebox? The point here is to use an orchestration that is stored and configured in Biztalk but avoid the performance loss of using a database to trigger it.

Answer (score 2):

Message box is an integral part of BizTalk server and no transaction can occur without message box. In most cases it works great and having message box provides lots of benefits for message delivery and processing. If you are having performance issues, I would recommend you measure your solution performance and identify bottlenecks. Some key points you can look:

- Orchestration Persistent points
- Use BizTalk host settings and change Polling intervals for messaging
  and Orchestration to reduce from 500 ms to 50 ms, it does help.
- If message box is a bottleneck (which is usually not the case until your volume is very high) add slave message boxes. BizTalk allows to scale out message box by adding slave message boxes. In this case one message box serves as master and rest others as slaves to process the request. [Scale out message box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296848(v=bts.10).aspx)

Comment: In the meanwhile we've found that if you already are running an orchestration it's possible to call another synchronously without using the messagebox according to this https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2009/08/15/difference-between-call-and-start-orchestration/

Comment: Your question was bit misleading. Phrasing your question to something like "call an orchestration from another orchestration without message box" would have made more sense.

Comment: Calling from another orchestration is a possibility we weren't aware of but other scenarios would be interesting as well. So the question wasn't misleading and I thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is NO, but, you are probably laboring under a false assumption.

There is no 'performance loss' due to the MessageBox.  If you can *prove* the MessageBox causes you to miss an SLA, then you should be considering a completely different app platform such as a Windows Service.  However, many of us have implemented very low latency apps with BizTalk without issue.

So, unless you SLA approaches the definition of 'real-time', I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Our Orchestrations, for the most part, call a web service that replies within a second. However wrapping that with an orchestration that maps the data and sends the reply back, adds seconds to the process. We would expect the external call to a web service to be what takes most of the time, but it doesn't. It's Biztalk who adds at least 4 seconds.

Comment: @Nuno Then you have something else going on or you local process legitimately takes 4 seconds.  For example, I'm looking right now at an app that handles synchronous EDI and both two-way operations takes will under one second.